# Creating DbGeometry instances that honor SRID

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, c#, sql-server

I maintain an ArcMap Add-in tasked with allowing people to see & edit some native SQL shapes in ArcMap, which of course require working with `SqlGeometry` and `DbGeometry` types. Converting between those two types has always generally gone well, until we started exploring migrating ArcMap from 10.6.1 to 10.8.0 & 10.8.1.  When run in 10.6, the extension method below returns a valid DbGeometry with a correct SRID (happens to be 102605).  But when run in 10.8, the very same method in the very same add-in throws an exception with the message "Cannot set DbGeometry's SRID properly -- 102605 vs 8826".

The add-in operates without problem in production on >100 PCs running ArcMap 10.6.1. The only instances of this problem have been on two test machines running ArcMap 10.8.1. Both of those test machines previously ran 10.6.1 (and handled these conversions just fine), which AFAICT pretty much nails it down to some change in ArcObjects causing this issue. What can cause this? Logging `typeof(DbSpatialServices).Assembly.FullName` in both environments yields the same: "EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089", so it would seem that the implementation behind `DbGeometry.FromBinary()` should be the same in both places, yeah?

```
public static DbGeometry ToDbGeometry(this SqlGeometry thisSqlGeometry)
{
    var dbGeometry = DbGeometry.FromBinary(thisSqlGeometry.STAsBinary().Buffer, thisSqlGeometry.STSrid.Value);
    if (dbGeometry.CoordinateSystemId != thisSqlGeometry.STSrid)
        throw new Exception($"Cannot set DbGeometry's SRID properly -- {thisSqlGeometry.STSrid.Value} vs {dbGeometry.CoordinateSystemId}");
    return dbGeometry;
}
```

Comment: ArcObjects bug reports should go to Esri Tech Support

Comment: I posted this question to the [esri community forums](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcobjects-sdk-questions/creating-dbgeometry-instances-that-honor-srid/td-p/1205643) as well. But (in spite of my investigations summarized above) I'm having a hard time seeing how this can be an esri bug.

Comment: Then it's a Microsoft bug, and you have the wrong tags, and the wrong forum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was my ignorance to Esri's deprecation of its own 102605 as the WKID for Idaho Transverse Mercator in favor of [EPSG's 8826](https://epsg.io/8826).  It looks like this was a broad-scale effort on their part affecting lots of spatial references that previously had no EPSG acknowledgement, and (at least for the WKIDs at issue here) it happened between 10.6 and 10.8, but I've found no announcement or doc from Esri about it.